# PHP + SQL Server 2012 - Violation of Primary Key constraint - How to avoid or help re-design logic

Tags: php, sql-server, primary-key

This may be more of a design/logic type question, but what I'm attempting to do is poll a web service which returns about 15 "records" of foo. I then take those 15 records and attempt a SQL INSERT with them. If I poll again and get back 20 records, I attempt an INSERT only on the new 5 records.

My problem is on the first page load, when it performs the first poll, it will always return all the records. When I do the initial INSERT, of course I will typically get a bunch of "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" errors. This is currently "by design", but I'm wondering if there's a better approach, or if this is an ok approach. Something about filling up the php error log repeatedly tells me it's not. :)

Is this resolved simply with a SQL-side Try/Catch?

Schema below:

[image]

Comment: Read about sql server's [merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: Added an "IF NOT EXISTS" and a "TRY CATCH" block - seems to have solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid causing errors, you can check which of the posts already exists with an SQL statment like this

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN ([id list])
```

where `id` is your primary key column, `table` the table (surprise) and `[id list]` a comma separated list of the id´s you want to insert. Use the PHP function `implode` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)) to create one if you have the id´s in a list.

Then just exclude the rows with the returned id´s.

Comment: Thought about doing this, but adds overhead to the "routine" of the polling->insert "round trip". The ID's are also created by SQL (that field is really pointless at the moment) as the ID's aren't generated by the web service. So I had to get creative with how I made the records unique. When doing my INSERT, I don't have any ID's to check against. This was one of the initial reasons I went with the "try it and if it fails, it'll go to the next record" approach.

Comment: So, I modified it to do a check first like below:
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EventsTable WHERE EventType LIKE 'Alarm' AND EventSource LIKE 'PACU-01 Main Sales, Space Hum' AND EventDescription LIKE 'Humidity too high' AND EventDateTime LIKE '07-25-2015 10:08:42' AND EventLocation LIKE '183')) BEGIN INSERT INTO EventsTable ( EventDateTime, EventType, EventSource, EventDescription, EventSubSystemKey, EventViewKey, EventLocation ) VALUES ('07-25-2015 10:08:42','Alarm','PACU-01 Main Sales, Space Hum','Humidity too high','2','14','183') END

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! When I run the statement directly in Mgmt Studio, I see the error and a line that says "The statement has been terminated." I don't see the error in the Apache error log however. This "feels" right. Thoughts?

Comment: If you have solved the problem yourself, you should post an answer to your own question. Also, you should update the original question with the information you gave me here in comments (about the multi-field primary key).